# Excel Formulas - Creating an OR array within a SUM

Tags: arrays, excel, sum, conditional-statements

The array formula I have currently is very close to what I want, it is only limited by the fact that I can only have two conditions (unless I want to manually add more).  What I'd like to do is be able to use a name derived from a table column to match criteria, similar to using OR() with a range.

As it stands, my array formula looks similar to this (using names or range references)

```
=SUM((JOB_HRS)*(TEXT($E4,"0")=TEXT(EMP_ID,"0"))*(JOB_DATE>=$M4)*(JOB_DATE<=$N4)*((JOB_TYPE=CONFIG!$F$8)+(JOB_TYPE=CONFIG!$F$9)))
```

I get a report sheet with about 5000 rows of data.  This formula accurately parses the sheet and sums up the total hours worked by an employee (by ID which is sometimes stored as a number or text based on the output programs' feelings that day)

The last part is what I'm looking to streamline

```
((JOB_TYPE=CONFIG!$F$8)+(JOB_TYPE=CONFIG!$F$9))
```

It works, but I am limited a bit by the amount of cells, plus the formula looks way long.  I'd like to simplify it to something like this, but cannot find a good reference to work with the SUM array.  Any thoughts?

```
(JOB_TYPE=RNG_OF_JOB_TYPES)
```

Edit: Added picture

[Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FKlF.png)

Comment: Any reason why you don't simply use a PivotTable?

Comment: From what I have found PivotTables use a hard coded reference for filters and I need to be able to update mine dynamically with cell references.

Comment: Use a Slicer to filter the Pivot. End result is the same, implementation and User Experience much simpler.

Comment: I suppose part of my reservation is formatting.  I have the sheet formatted perfectly to print on one sheet.  I don't want a PivotTable to grow and shrink. Plus I am trying to super restrict what the end-user can adjust on the sheet itself using protected cells and it is very heavy with conditional formatting.  I could do this with VBA super easy, but I am even limited with the security policies on the computers this will be used on.

Comment: Won't the PivotTable show the exact same amount of records as your formula? Also, will this formula be executed for each and every Emp_ID? How many of those do you have?  Have you looked at the SUMIFS function? Note that SUMIF/SUMIFS are computationally expensive, and should be used sparingly. The last thing you want is a worksheet with tens of thousands of SUMIFS in it.

Comment: The Emp_ID is what will change in each row.  The formula only occurs in 1 column, I have a lot of other summary data that needs to be expressed inline with it as a single source document that a PivotTable will not fit into.  This is something that needs to be easily copied into a PowerPoint and briefed to CEO type people who don't have time to decipher it.  I literally need only the 1 result of the formula to fit into a single cell.

Comment: If you have Emp_ID in the Rows pane and whatever other specific columns you want in the Rows or Columns pane, then how would the PivotTable take up any more space than say a formulas solution? I think I'm missing something...

Comment: Are you going to have those Emp_IDs hard coded? Is there any possibility they would change in future? Isn't it better to use a PivotTable in that case, so you get a complete list of Emp_IDs, rather than some that might be redundant? Sorry to harp on about PivotTables...just trying to understand your requirements and make sure you get the best approach given them :-)

Comment: I use a column that has data validation to select Emp by Name, which populates the ID in a hidden column. The sheet is ordered by hard coded employee positions, from which employees will change out periodically. I will upload a snippet of what the result needs to look like. The columns to the right are the calculated columns based on my original formula.  I would just like to update it to allow for more criteria dynamically.

Comment: So you have around 5000 employees that need to be shown? Or it this more of an ad-hoc report where users select a handful of employees of interest?

Comment: More ad-hoc.  I have only 42 employees to track.  What is lengthy is I have 5000 rows of hours for flights

Comment: I just really prefer the specific control I have over formatting and layout.

Comment: I use custom PivotTable Styles to make pivots look exactly like I want them. But I'm hopelessly biased...I think PivotTables are the best way to do practically anything, and use them instead of VBA or Formulas wherever I can.

Comment: Another way to have the best of both worlds is to use a PivotTable on a hidden sheet to do the number crunching, and then retrieve the specific answers you want using the awesome GETPIVOTDATA function. Have incorporated this into my answer.

Comment: I suppose I am biased against them. I actually prefer Access but I need to keep this tracker simple... I suppose I am looking for something similar to *(IF(MATCH(FLTD_ACFT_MDS,CFG_PRIACFT,0),1,0)) but this is returning an error, though it works in a count array.

Comment: `MAX(--(JOB_TYPE=RNG_OF_JOB_TYPES))` should give 0 if none are true, and 1 if any one is true

Comment: Is there a way to use MAX in conjunction with SUM()*()? I am getting an error with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet formula-wise is to use the SUMIFS formula. You will still need to specify each criteria individually, but the syntax is much simpler:

```
=SUMIFS(sum_range,criteria_range,criteria,...)
```

But as discussed, my personal preference is to use PivotTables to do number crunching. Sometimes I put the Pivot on a hidden sheet, and use the GETPIVOTDATA function in the sheet exposed to the user to get inputs and go retrieve the aggregated value from the PivotTable. This gives you complete flexibility over formatting.